# MagicalRecord saveWithBlock usage now fails to compile under XCode 7 beta 5

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, magicalrecord

I just updated to beta 5 of XCode 7 and am now getting a compliation error on the following Swift code:

```
MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({ (localContext : NSManagedObjectContext!) in
    // ... Save models here ...
    }, completion: { (success : Bool, error : NSError!) in
    // ... Handle completion here ...
})
```

Under previous builds of XCode 7, this compiled fine, but I'm now getting:

> Cannot invoke 'saveWithBlock' with an argument list of type '((NSManagedObjectContext!) -> (), completion: (Bool, NSError!) -> ())'

I've tried adding `-> Void` (as autocompleted when I try to add the call afresh) and `-> Void!` to the parameters, but see the same error.

Is this a language change or a bug in this XCode build?

**EDIT** (5.42pm ETC 08/08/2015): Calling savedWithBlock without the completion handler appears to compile ok:

```
MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock { (localContext: NSManagedObjectContext!) -> Void in
   // ... Save models here ...
}
```

**EDIT** (8.32am ETC 08/11/2015): Following recommendation by @Gerd Castan, I also tried changing the completion parameter to:

```
completion: { (success : Bool, error : ErrorType!)
```

and

```
completion: { (success : ObjCBool, error : ErrorType!)
```

Both of which gave the same error.

Comment: Which branch/pod are you using? (I'm looking into MagicalRecord but it's not clear to me which branch is Xcode 7 compatible... I would guess 3.0?)

Comment: I've been using the master branch (currently at 2.3.0) and it's been working ok for me. Have you had issues?

Comment: No, haven't tried it yet – doing a little research to see how well it works in the Swift 2 environment, especially since all the docs are in Objective C...

Comment: Ok, I can recommend just using the master, there's a bit of translation to do for the Swift syntax, but the autocomplete's pretty good as at this beta. Any trouble, feel free to ping me via Twitter (link in my profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be fixed with XCode 7 Beta 6. The syntax:

```
MagicalRecord.saveWithBlock({ (localContext: NSManagedObjectContext!) -> Void in
    // Save model here
}) { (success: Bool, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    // Handle result here
}
```

Compiles without error.

Answer (score 0):

Apple replaced NSError with ErrorType.

Replace your own explicit usage of NSError with ErrorType to avoid this type of compiler errors.

Comment: Unfortunately, after making that changes, I'm still seeing the same error.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I was able to fix several similar compiler errors that way.